# Automatic Lazyloading on Entity Framework 4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lazy-loading, poco

Suppose I have an Entity Order with OrderDetails as child preperty.

I enable lazyloading like this:

```
  _context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

I Can feed a view with a method like this:

Order.GetAll()

And navigate by the order details automatically without getting the wirerd "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error??

Comment: I think you may need to provide more code. That error could be referring to a lot of different things other than your entities. And yes, enabling lazy loading will allow you to access your OrderDetails entities through a navigation property without the need to explicitly load it from the data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have lazy loading, when you load up the objects you need to explicitly include the sub objects.

So Order.GetAll() will include

```
return context.Orders.Include("OrderDetails");
```

Another alternative is to load up the order details later, like so:

```
if (!order.OrderDetailsHeaders.IsLoaded)
{
    order.OrderDetailsHeaders.Load();
}
```

Comment: I think the above applies if lazy loading is set to false, not true... correct?

Comment: @Scott, no I don't think so. Lazy loading means that child elements are not loaded when an entity is loaded. You have to explicitly load child entities using .Include or .Load.

Comment: @Mac, you are correct that LazyLoadingEnabled=true; will not load children when an entity is loaded... but it will automatically load any entity the first time you try to access it with a navigation property without requiring you to explicitly load it yourself. Alternatively, you can use .Include to load children immediately, or set LazyLoadingEnabled=false; and call .Load before you need to access an entity. See this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontextoptions.lazyloadingenabled.aspx

Comment: Sorry for the messy guys.....I Just forgot to put my business objects as virtual properties. Thanks for all.

Comment: @Scott, I disagree that the framework will automatically load it the first time you access the properties. I have had many occasions where I've been banging my head against the monitor wondering why the property is null when there is clearly data in the database only to realise my Include statements were not loading up that object.

Comment: @Mac, According to the following MSDN link, the second sentence states: "With lazy loading enabled, related objects are loaded when they are accessed through a navigation property." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456846.aspx

Comment: However, if you have a Teacher object, that has a navigation property to a "Class" object, which in turn has a a navigation property to a "School" object. Lazy Loading will not always work if you call: myTeacher.Class.School (because myTeacher.Class might be null) You could however call: myTeacher.Class (which lazily loads the Class) then call myTeacher.Class.School later in code and it will work because we know that Class was loaded from an earlier call. Hope that makes sense.